no option in visual studio to enter password to connect to host
We have connected our host website in visual studio to work on project.
we changed password through hostinger dashboard. now when we tried to connect to that host, we are getting an error as below . also we are not seeing any option to enter new password to connect to host. we are not using .ppk file but we are using password.


The error message is telling you what to do, and it is not an issue with the password itself.
This happens whenever the fingerprint for that host changes. I would guess that changing the password changed the host's fingerprint.
Navigate to C:\Users\<your profile folder>\.ssh and open the knownhosts file (please consider taking a backup of this file first). Find the fingerprint corresponding to the host in question and delete it. According to the message it should be the 9th host or 9th line in this file. Then reconnect.
You'll be prompted whether you wish to trust the host again, which will save the new fingerprint to the knownhosts file, and things should work.
Notice that this is the same information the message told you. Knowing this will be helpful to remind yourself next time this happens.
